# Checkout issues

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I manage a shop that runs on CE 1.5.*. And gets lot of drop offs in checkout pages.
Checkout page takes a lot of time to load. I run on multiple servers with 7.5 G of RAM with a php memory limit of 3.5 G.

So thinking of moving my checkouts to a separate server of little bit more resources may be a 32 G RAM. and more CPU capacity.
Planning to redirect all requests to URL ~checkout/onepage/ to a separate server.

Is this is something achievable with Magento.
My customer sessions are in a separate Mongo server

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is achievable, but no magento problem. You want to configure your load balance the right way.

But instead of throwing resouces on this problem, you should check why magento needs so much RAM (if you don't have much customers)

Comment: The daily visits are around 100 thousand and around 4 thousand reach checkout page. just above 1 thousands gets converted to successful orders.

Comment: Oh, ok then you are one of the few who have real problems. I still think optimizing is worth trying, the question is, what happend from the customer point of view.

Comment: The step2- to step3 (I use gomage-checkout) is taking lot of time. so we see a lot of drop offs there. as well as in step-3 where people who opt for COD. Waits for at least 5-10 secs to get the ajax response

Comment: Just a quick question: Will migrating to EE will solve my issue with checkout. I am ready to explore that possibility also.

Comment: @Serpyre: Currently it is with AWS. Uses varnish to server category and product as well as all static pages. Varnish shows almost 80 % hit as well. So i am feeling that i have reached a road block now

Comment: @Serpyre:I was trying to say even most of my traffic is served by varnish I am not able to support this small number of checkouts. And the target is 2500 checkouts per day in a matter of weeks. So any hint in which direction i should take my next step. (Adding: my db servers are fine)

Comment: you should think about changing the checkout. I don't know whether newer versions of GoMageCheckout are better, but a controller with 1400 lines of code and one action with 1k of lines are damn wrong and I think there is a lot which can be optimized.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: Thanks a lot. Will look for alternatives